# R force reinstall packages

Tags: r, package, installation

I ran the command `update.packages(checkBuilt = TRUE, ask = FALSE)`.

However my html directories were not writable and I got a lot of:

```
Warning in file.create(f.tg) :
cannot create file '/usr/share/doc/R-3.0.1/html/packages.html', reason 'Permission denied'
```

Is there a way to force reinstall all packages now that I've fixed my permissions issues, so I get those HTML files? The code part got installed correctly, so `update.packages` doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 7):

`install.packages` installs a package even if it exists in your library. And of course it will be in the latest version.

Answer (score 5):

You could run this script:

```
lib_loc <- "[library location]"
to_install <- unname(installed.packages(lib.loc = lib_loc)[, "Package"])
install.packages(pkgs = to_install)
```

If you are using the default library:

```
to_install <- unname(installed.packages()[, "Package"])
install.packages(pkgs = to_install)
```

Answer (score 1):

I could not install a requirement because of lack of libgit2-devel, I installed it and reran the install.packages('devtools') but it just completed right away.  You could just remove.packages('name') and then install again.

```
Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
Making 'packages.html' ... done
```

Answer (score 1):

Force reinstall (recompile) all! packages:

```
allPackages <- installed.packages()[,"Package"]
exclude = c("base", "compiler", "datasets", "graphics", "grDevices", "grid", "methods", "parallel", "splines", "stats", "stats4", "tcltk", "tools", "utils")
packages = allPackages[!allPackages %in% exclude]
install.packages(pkgs = packages, clean = TRUE, quiet = FALSE)
```