# Upgrade all standard packages while retaining non-standard packages

Tags: r, customization, upgrade, cran

Sometimes GNU R has a problem whereby Hadley Wickham [recommends](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/1963):

> I'd recommend re-installing all your packages.

The question is how to do this in the best possible way. I know that `install.packages` or `update.packages` will upgrade all package versions and [overwrite existing versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24999368/r-force-reinstall-packages):

```r
update.packages(checkBuilt = TRUE, ask = FALSE)
```

When using CRAN packages (nothing special from GitHub or other sources), this naive approach worked for me:

```
my.packages <- rownames(installed.packages());
install.packages(my.packages);
```

What can I do if I have [installed dev versions from GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9656016/how-to-install-development-version-of-r-packages-github-repository), for example, or used some local packages that are not shared publicly?

What I am looking for is a way to:

1. check which changes to packages result from new installation (upgrades/downgrades);
2. install packages again from the same source; and
3. back up my old packages folder.

How can I address these requirements?

Comment: Do you use RStudio? If so you could always go to the packages tab and click on update, would that be an option?

Comment: have you considered using [packrat](https://rstudio.github.io/packrat/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partial solution for (1) - find out which packages will be upgraded/downgraded:

```r
my.packages <- installed.packages();
my.avail <- available.packages();

z <- merge(
      my.packages[,c("Package","Version")],
      my.avail[,c("Package","Version")],
      by = "Package", suffixes = c('.my','.avail'));

z$Version.my <- as.character(z$Version.my)
z$Version.avail <- as.character(z$Version.avail)

# my packages which will be upgraded
subset(z, Version.my < Version.avail)

# my packages that will be downgraded
subset(z, Version.my > Version.avail)
```

This is only approximate, I think - depending on dependencies you may not get all the upgrades. But you should see the downgrades to expect if using dev versions?

Another way to upgrade all packages is to use the following:

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following method.

```
libLoc<-.libPaths()[1]
update.packages(lib.loc = libLoc, instlib = libLoc, checkBuilt = TRUE, ask = FALSE)
```

Here `lib.loc` is the location of the existing packages you want to update and `instlib` is the location for the new packages(same in the above example snippet). Avoid passing `lib.loc` or set it to `NULL` if you want to update all existing packages(not just the ones in `libLoc`) but place all the new updated packages in `instlib` location. Check out the documentation of `update.packages` function for more information.

I used this when I had issues with packages and had to reinstall them after upgrading to R-3.5 from older version on a remote system where I had limited privileges.

Hope this helps.