# rsession(9608) MallocStackLogging error in RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio

Out of a sudden I get the following warning when typing in `RStudio`:

```
rsession(9608) MallocStackLogging: can't turn off malloc stack logging because it was not enabled.
```

Everytime when I'm typing in RStudio the warning appears with a different rsession like this:

```
rsession(9608) MallocStackLogging: can't turn off malloc stack logging because it was not enabled.
rsession(9640) MallocStackLogging: can't turn off malloc stack logging because it was not enabled.
rsession(9641) MallocStackLogging: can't turn off malloc stack logging because it was not enabled.
rsession(9652) MallocStackLogging: can't turn off malloc stack logging because it was not enabled.
rsession(9653) MallocStackLogging: can't turn off malloc stack logging because it was not enabled.
rsession(9655) MallocStackLogging: can't turn off malloc stack logging because it was not enabled.
rsession(9656) MallocStackLogging: can't turn off malloc stack logging because it was not enabled.
rsession(9659) MallocStackLogging: can't turn off malloc stack logging because it was not enabled.
rsession(9661) MallocStackLogging: can't turn off malloc stack logging because it was not enabled.
rsession(9700) MallocStackLogging: can't turn off malloc stack logging because it was not enabled.
rsession(9701) MallocStackLogging: can't turn off malloc stack logging because it was not enabled.
```

There is an [issue](https://github.com/withfig/fig/issues/2660) about this warning, but I can't find anything related to `rstudio`. So, I was wondering if anyone knows what this error is and why it happens?

---

**Please note:** I'm using a MacBook Pro with Intel Core i5 2020.

Comment: [IOS Memory Leaks? and tools to address](https://www.netguru.com/blog/what-are-ios-memory-leaks-and-how-to-detect-them), perhaps completely erroneous.

Comment: This started happening to me when I upgraded to macOS 14.2.1. Did you find a fix?

Comment: Hi @n.g.davies, Unfortunately, I haven't found a fix. The message still appears to me.

Comment: Thanks @Quinten. Maybe we can compare notes on this. I have a MacBook Pro i7 2019, and use gcc version 13.1.0 (Homebrew GCC 13.1.0). I'm using R 4.3.1; now upgrading to 4.3.2 and will reinstall all packages to see if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this same issue after upgrading to macOS Sonoma (14.2.1), running R 4.3.1 and using gcc version 13.1.0 (Homebrew) as my C/C++ compiler.

I was able to fix it by upgrading to R 4.3.2 and reinstalling all R packages (following the approach for "the default library" [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61470314/6624951)).

While doing so, I specifically installed `data.table`, `Rcpp`, `RcppEigen`, and `RcppArmadillo` from source e.g.:

```
install.packages(c("data.table", "Rcpp", "RcppEigen", "RcppArmadillo"), type = "source")
```

because that is what I normally do on a fresh R install. However, I doubt that this was the critical step.

I am not sure which of these steps is/are the critical ones:

- reinstalling R;
- upgrading to 4.3.2;
- or reinstalling all packages;

but the combination seems to have resolved the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

I also had this issue on Sonoma (14.2.1) and solved it by updating R from 4.3.1 to 4.3.2. So that might be the place to start then.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue, but updating R didn't fix it. However, I was able to solve it by re-installing [Rtools](https://mac.thecoatlessprofessor.com/macrtools/)